# process measure group and dimension VS Process cube

Tags: process, ssas, cube

When new data coming, When I process dimenstion first and then measure group, up-to-date data will show  without processing cube. Dpes this mean it is not necessary to process cube ?

Any help ?

Answer (score 0):

If all you have in your cube is dimensions and measures, then yes, you do not need to process the cube after processing dimensions and measure groups.

Answer (score 0):

looks MOLAP for Dimensions and ROLAP for Measuregroups.

we don`t need cube process for rolap. rolap result is directly from sql.